# Error when using an INSERT statement to enter new data - duplicate key?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to run the below stored procedure that I wrote to fulfill this requirement: ***Write a procedure ProcedureName (p_snum, p_CallNum) to add/enroll a student to the course.***

```
Create or Replace Procedure ThreeOne(

  p_snum number,
  p_CallNum number

  ) AS

  Begin
    insert into Students (snum) values (p_snum);
    insert into SchClasses (callnum) values (p_callnum);
    commit;
    rollback;

  end;
  /
  set SERVEROUTPUT on 
  Execute ThreeOne(500,10500)
```

However upon doing so, I'm getting the following error in Oracle Developer, and I'm unsure how to remedy the issue.  It's probably blatantly obvious, but I would like to understand what's happening to improve my technique:

```
Error starting at line : 17 in command -
Execute ThreeOne(500,10500)
Error report -
ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORY.SYS_C0012641) violated
ORA-06512: at "CORY.THREEONE", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1
00001. 00000 -  "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
           For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see
           this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.
```

My database table creation file data:

```
drop table enrollments;
drop table prereq;
drop table schclasses;
drop table courses;
drop table students;
drop table majors;

-----
-----


create table MAJORS
    (major varchar2(3) Primary key,
    mdesc varchar2(30));
insert into majors values ('ACC','Accounting');
insert into majors values ('FIN','Finance');
insert into majors values ('IS','Information Systems');
insert into majors values ('MKT','Marketing');

create table STUDENTS 
    (snum varchar2(3) primary key,
    sname varchar2(10),
    standing number(1),
    major varchar2(3) constraint fk_students_major references majors(major),
    gpa number(2,1),
    major_gpa number(2,1));

insert into students values ('101','Andy',4,'IS',2.8,3.2);
insert into students values ('102','Betty',2,null,3.2,null);
insert into students values ('103','Cindy',3,'IS',2.5,3.5);
insert into students values ('104','David',2,'FIN',3.3,3.0);
insert into students values ('105','Ellen',1,null,2.8,null);
insert into students values ('106','Frank',3,'MKT',3.1,2.9);

create table COURSES
    (dept varchar2(3) constraint fk_courses_dept references majors(major),
    cnum varchar2(3),
    ctitle varchar2(30),
    crhr number(3),
    standing number(1),
    primary key (dept,cnum));

insert into courses values ('IS','300','Intro to MIS',3,2);
insert into courses values ('IS','301','Business Communicatons',3,2);
insert into courses values ('IS','310','Statistics',3,2);
insert into courses values ('IS','355','Networks',3,3);
insert into courses values ('IS','380','Database',3,3);
insert into courses values ('IS','385','Systems',3,3);
insert into courses values ('IS','480','Adv Database',3,4);
insert into courses values ('IS','340','Application Programming',3,4);

create table SCHCLASSES (
    callnum number(5) primary key,
    year number(4),
    semester varchar2(3),
    dept varchar2(3),
    cnum varchar2(3),
    section number(2),
    capacity number(3));

alter table schclasses 
    add constraint fk_schclasses_dept_cnum foreign key 
    (dept, cnum) references courses (dept,cnum);

insert into schclasses values (10110,2013,'Sp','IS','300',1,45);
insert into schclasses values (10115,2013,'Sp','IS','300',2,35);
insert into schclasses values (10120,2013,'Sp','IS','380',3,35);
insert into schclasses values (10125,2013,'Fa','IS','300',1,118);
insert into schclasses values (10130,2013,'Fa','IS','301',1,33);
insert into schclasses values (10135,2014,'Fa','IS','310',1,35);
insert into schclasses values (10140,2014,'Fa','IS','310',2,35);
insert into schclasses values (10145,2014,'Fa','IS','340',1,30);
insert into schclasses values (10150,2014,'Fa','IS','380',1,33);
insert into schclasses values (10155,2014,'Fa','IS','385',1,35);
insert into schclasses values (10160,2014,'Fa','IS','480',1,35);

create table PREREQ
    (dept varchar2(3),
    cnum varchar2(3),
    pdept varchar2(3),
    pcnum varchar2(3),
    primary key (dept, cnum, pdept, pcnum));
alter table Prereq 
    add constraint fk_prereq_dept_cnum foreign key 
    (dept, cnum) references courses (dept,cnum);
alter table Prereq 
    add constraint fk_prereq_pdept_pcnum foreign key 
    (pdept, pcnum) references courses (dept,cnum);

insert into prereq values ('IS','380','IS','300');
insert into prereq values ('IS','380','IS','301');
insert into prereq values ('IS','380','IS','310');
insert into prereq values ('IS','385','IS','310');
insert into prereq values ('IS','340','IS','300');
insert into prereq values ('IS','480','IS','380');

create table ENROLLMENTS (
    snum varchar2(3) constraint fk_enrollments_snum references students(snum),
    callnum number(5) constraint fk_enrollments_callnum references schclasses(callnum),
    grade varchar2(2),
    primary key (snum, callnum));

insert into enrollments values (101,10110,'A');
insert into enrollments values (102,10110,'B');
insert into enrollments values (103,10120,'A');
insert into enrollments values (101,10125,null);
insert into enrollments values (102,10130,null);
insert into enrollments values (104,10150,'A');
insert into enrollments values (102,10155,'C');
insert into enrollments values (101,10150,'B');
insert into enrollments values (103,10155,'A');
insert into enrollments values (101,10155,'B');
insert into enrollments values (103,10150,'A');





create table S (
    S# varchar2(3),
    SNAME varchar2(20),
    STATUS number(5),
    CITY varchar2(20),
    primary key (S#)
);

insert into S values ('S1','Smith',20,'London');
insert into S values ('S2','Jones',10,'Paris');
insert into S values ('S3','Blake',30,'Paris');
insert into S values ('S4','Clark',20,'London');
insert into S values ('S5','Adams',30,'Athens');

create table P (
    P# varchar2(3),
    PNAME varchar2(20),
    COLOR varchar2(20),
    WEIGHT number(5),
    CITY varchar2(20),
    primary key (P#)
);

insert into P values ('P1','Nut','Red',12,'London');
insert into P values ('P2','Bolt','Green',17,'Paris');
insert into P values ('P3','Screw','Blue',17,'Rome');
insert into P values ('P4','Screw','Red',14,'London');
insert into P values ('P5','Cam','Blue',12,'Paris');
insert into P values ('P6','Cog','Red',19,'London');

create table SP (
    S# varchar2(3),
    P# varchar2(3),
    QTY number(10),
    primary key (S#,P#)
);
alter table SP
    add constraint fk_inventory_supplier foreign key (S#) references S (S#);
alter table SP
    add constraint fk_inventory_product foreign key (P#) references P (P#);

insert into SP values ('S1','P1',300);
insert into SP values ('S1','P2',200);
insert into SP values ('S1','P3',400);
insert into SP values ('S1','P4',200);
insert into SP values ('S1','P5',100);
insert into SP values ('S1','P6',100);
insert into SP values ('S2','P1',300);
insert into SP values ('S2','P2',400);
insert into SP values ('S3','P2',200);
insert into SP values ('S4','P2',200);
insert into SP values ('S4','P4',300);
insert into SP values ('S4','P5',400);

create table CUSTOMERS (
    CNUM varchar2(3),
    CNAME varchar2(20),
    ACCOUNTBALANCE number(12,2),
    TOTALMILAGE number(10),
    primary key (CNUM)
);

insert into CUSTOMERS values ('101','Andy',85.25,2152);
insert into CUSTOMERS values ('102','Betty',170.00,108);
insert into CUSTOMERS values ('103','Cindy',-55.13,3);
insert into CUSTOMERS values ('104','David',1308.02,5510);
insert into CUSTOMERS values ('105','Ellen',99.77,11150);
insert into CUSTOMERS values ('106','Frank',-0.02,80);


commit;
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try getting an `INSERT` to work, then remove columns until it starts to break.

Comment: Could it be because I have CallNum and SNUM defined as the primary keys? If that's the case.. how do I pass information to these values in an insert procedure then?

Comment: You are entering a duplicate record.  Check your data carefully.

Comment: You're creating a duplicate record that violates your primary key constraint. Do you understand that a primary key means a unique value that can't be duplicated? I spotted it in 10 seconds of reviewing your SQL content, and I've never seen it before. Surely you can spot it if you read through the code. You only need to look at the two tables you're inserting into in your procedure, and the values you're using when you call that procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I realized that I was in fact attempting to insert duplicate data that already existed.  Furthermore, I realized that I was using the wrong assignments for the parameter types, and not allowing the appropiate amount of space and data type for variable pass.

Thanks all for your help!